# viewPager.setCurrentItem not working inside adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, adapter

I'm using an adapter to populate view from Firebase to a CardView. I'm trying to open a new fragment with onclicklistener on an item from the cardView inside the adapter. It used to work when I was not using fragments, to open Activity2 as shown below:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload upload = (Upload) this.uploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(upload.getName());
    Glide.with(this.context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
    holder.textViewYear.setText(upload.getYr());
    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Now while using fragments, I tried with viewpager inside my adapter to select another view when the card is clicked, which doesn't work. Every time I launch the app it crashes with click on the card:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload upload = (Upload) this.uploads.get(position);
    holder.make.setText(upload.getName());
    Glide.with(this.context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
    holder.year.setText(upload.getYr());
    
    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my crash logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: greeny.cop, PID: 22602
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at greeny.cop.Adapter.CarPath$1.onClick(CarPath.java:61)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4446)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18430)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5281)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:932)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:748)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: how do you initilaze viewpager inside holder?

Comment: The viewpager was initialized in the fragment that is using the adapter like that: viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container)

I tried to do the same inside the adapter, but it said cannot resolve method on the getActivity.

public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            
            viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container);

        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have your view pager in your Fragment.

Your ViewPager is not initialized and the way you have initialized your Viewpager is incorrect.

You could use an interface to do this.

Create an interface

```
public interface ViewPagerListener{
    void setViewPager(int position);
}
```

Implement the interface in your Fragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements ViewPagerListener{

    //method to be implemented.
    public void setViewPager(int position){
       //TODO: do your implementation here
    }

}
```

Add a `ViewPagerListener` param in your adapter in one of the constructor

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Obj>{

    Context c;
    ArrayList<Obj> objects
    ViewPagerListener mListener;

    public MyAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<Obj> objects,ViewPagerListener mListener){
        this.c = c;
        this.objects = objects;
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }

}
```

In your Fragment, initialize your Adapter like this

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),objects,MyFragment.this); //3rd param is your interface instance.
```

Call the interface method in your adapter `onBindViewHolder` method

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload upload = (Upload) this.uploads.get(position);
    holder.make.setText(upload.getName());
    Glide.with(this.context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
    holder.year.setText(upload.getYr());

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mListener.setViewPager(3) // Calling the interface method
        }
    });
}
```

You can set the ViewPager position in your fragment like this

```
public void setViewPager(int position){
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck :)